# How to avoid calling the same function with the same parameters twice?

Tags: haskell

I have a piece of code like this

```
if (result-of-a-func-call) > 0
    then (result-of-a-func-call)
    else -2
```

Is there a way to avoid calling the same function (with the same parameters) the second time? In an imperative language, we can do something like

```
if((result=func-call())>0)
    result
else
    -2
```

Comment: `where`/`let` clause.

Comment: Does `result-of-a-func-call` has any argument ? If not `if f > 0 then f else -2` will only call `f` once.

Comment: `result-of-a-func-call` does have arguments. I ommitted them for simplicity. Now I think that `func` without the arguments does the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `case`

```
case theFunction x of
    x | x < 0 -> -2
    x -> x
```

That being said, this looks like a c style error detection to me (ie- if result of function is < 0, there is an error, otherwise the result is the value).  In Haskell, don't do this!

Instead use monads.  For instance, use Maybe.

```
case theFunction x of
    Nothing -> handle error
    Just x -> x
```

(if handling the error just means passing it up to the next level, you often won't even need the `case` at all, the monad logic will handle it correctly)

You can do something similar using `Either`, where you can distinguish between error types.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using `let` or `where`:

```
f x =
    let y = g x
    in if y > 0 then y else -2
```

Or

```
f x = if y > 0 then y else -2
    where y = g x
```

There are subtle differences between the two here, the biggest one to keep in mind is that `where` can be used to define values that don't change in between function calls and the compiler will only define the value once, while a local `let` will be defined every time the function is called, e.g.

```
f x = g x
    where g y = y * y + 1
```

versus

```
f x =
    let g y = y * y + 1
    in g x
```

In the first example, `g` is defined only once since it does not depend on any of `f`'s arguments (`x`), while in the second example `g` is redefined every time `f` is called.  There are reasons for wanting both approaches that are beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Am I wrong or `result-of-func-call` won't be called a second time but *memoize* by the compiler ? Or does it depends if `result-of-func-call` as 0 or many parameters. What I mean is haskell is lazy so `result-of-func-call` is lazy and `if y > 0 then y else -2` is strictly identical to the OP original question. `y` could potentially be called twice.

Comment: @mb14 The name `y` would be initially bound to the thunk of `g x`.  Once that thunk is forced via `y > 0`, the name `y` would be bound to the normal form result of `g x`.  You can verify this in GHCi using the `:sprint` command: `let g x = x + 1`; `let y = g (1 :: Int)` (type signature needed to prevent `y :: Num a => a`); `:sprint y` prints out `y = _`; `y > 0` prints out `True`; `:sprint y` prints out `y = 2`.  If you are really paranoid, use `Debug.Trace.trace`, but I guarantee you that Haskell's laziness is not going to cause `g` to be called twice.

Comment: @mb14 The only problem would come from if OP had `func_call` as a monadic function, such as `func_call :: IO Int`, but then it would be impossible to do `func_call > 2` as `IO` does not implement `Ord` anyway.  With pure functions, so long as you've bound the result to a name the compiler won't call the function twice, or else `let y = x * x in y * y * y` would mean the same as `x * x * x * x * x * x` and no one would use Haskell for high performance computing.

Comment: my question was more, if you call `g x` twice within the same function, will it be evaluated twice ?

Comment: @mb14 If you had `if g x > 0 then g x else -2`, `g x` would be evaluated twice, yes.  The compiler could potentially identify this as an optimization, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: What I also meant, it seems the OP is mixed up with imperative and language and thinks `if f() >0 then f() else -2` will call `f` twice. In that case it's question it's specific to function call without argument. In that case `f x = if y > 0 then y else -2 where x = y` is not better than `f x = if x > 0 then x else -2`.  ;-)

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks for your answer. Since I don't know, how the compiler really works, I used to think `y` would be called twice.